# HTML <ruby> elements word spacing using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing a hobby project for fun recently, it's a GitHub webpage using Jekyll.

One of the main component of my site is displaying Chinese characters with their Sino-Vietnamese pronunciation. I use `<ruby>` elements to render these texts, for those who don't know, you can read its [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby)

The problem with that is word spacing is broken when a `<rt>` element is longer than its associated `<rb>` element. So I created a jQuery function to dynamically adjust spacing.

A minimal example here:

```js
const stdSpace = "1em"; // for ruby annotation spacing
$(function () {
    $("rb").each(rubyAdjust);
});
function rubyAdjust(i, el) { // for each ruby base
    const rbW = $(el).width(), // take its width
          rtW = $(el).next("rt").width(), // its associated ruby text width
          diff = (rtW - rbW).toFixed(0), // excess amount
          addSpace = diff > 0
                     ? `calc(${stdSpace} + ${diff.toString()}px)`
                     : stdSpace;
    $(el).css("margin-right", addSpace);
}
```

```css
rb {
    display: inline-block /* fluid word spacing with margin using JS */
}

rt {
    text-align: left /* to work together with rb margin */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ruby>
    <rb>是</rb><rt>Thị</rt>
    <rb>故</rb><rt>cố</rt>
    <rb>空</rb><rt>không</rt>
    <rb>中</rb><rt>trung</rt>
</ruby>
```

My function `rubyAdjust` works as expected, but becomes a UI blocking point when I have a very long text. For a full fledged example, you can visit [a page of my project which shows the Diamond Sutra](https://phineas-pta.github.io/kinh_nhat_tung/chanh-kinh/kinh-kim-cang.html).

So what I want is to improve the rendering speed:

1. Is there a better way to adjust word spacing of `<ruby>`? The official docs of `<ruby>` doesn't have much, maybe because the feature is still uncomplete and fews people are using it?
2. I've also searched for a multi thread execution of jQuery, but it seems like DOM manipulation isn't possible. Do you guys have any idea?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some improvements:

- completely remove the JS function and replace with CSS (thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877801/10805680)); this greatly reduces loading time
- wrap one `ruby` for each pair `rb` & `rt` with `ruby`, instead of having multiple pairs of them inside `ruby`
- use `flex` to render rather than the default `display: block`

The improved code:

```css
ruby {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    margin-right: 0.5em; /* additional spacing */
}

rb, rt {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1; /* spacing between rb & rt can be changed */
    text-align: left; /* my personal preference */
}
```

```html
<ruby><rb>是</rb><rt>Thị</rt></ruby>
<ruby><rb>故</rb><rt>cố</rt></ruby>
<ruby><rb>空</rb><rt>không</rt></ruby>
<ruby><rb>中</rb><rt>trung</rt></ruby>
```